# homeUrl doesn't work in form action

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I have created a form with a search button above it. 
I write something in the search box and submit it but it returns to web/index?search='something'.
I want it to return to where I am now. I mean, index and I use the following code:

```
<form action="<?=Yii::$app->homeUrl?>?r=phone/index">
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

- phone is my controller and index is the page I have my form in.

Thanks

Comment: How about leaving the action attribute as empty: `action=""`, the form would be submitted to the orriginal controller action!

Comment: i have also tried that and the same error occurs. it seems leaving it empty and giving it the homeUrl does the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

`homeUrl` will send you to where you've configured it or to it's the default location if you haven't. Try this if you want to send the form data to the same URL where the form is:

```
yii\helpers\Url::to();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"<?=Yii::$app->homeUrl?>?r=phone/index"
```

By:

```
"<?=\yii\helpers\Url::to(['phone/index'])?>"
```